# How to Install redshift plasmoid?

Tags: ubuntu, plasma

Using Ubuntu 15.10

I am trying to follow the instructions [here](https://github.com/simgunz/redshift-plasmoid) to install the redshift plasmoid GUI, and cannot find the redshift root directory, does anyone know where this should be located? I've used the find and locate commands to search for any directories and files called "redshift" to no avail(a couple of files but no root directory).

Does anyone know how to install redshift plasmoid properly? I have installed plasma-widget-redshift from the repository, but I can't seem to start it, or find it anywhere. The only knew binary is redshiftautostart, which doesn't do anything, even after a reboot.